matlab code of an linear-matrix-inequality(LMI)
In the following linear-matrix-inequality (LMI) ${\sigma}_1 $to ${\sigma }_4$ are unknown parameters and other parameters are known parameters. I see somewhere the matlab code of this LMI but this code is not obvious for me. Can anyone please help me  to explain  this code? Any hint would be helpful.
\begin{align} 
 \begin{split}
  \Big({\sigma }_1+h_m{\sigma }_2+\frac{{h_m}^2}{2}{\sigma }_3+{h}_m{\sigma }_4\Big){\delta }^2\le {\beta }^{-1},
 \end{split}
\end{align}
Matlab code:
lmiterm([-1 1 1 Sigma1 ],1,1)      ;
lmiterm([-1 1 1 Sigma2 ],hm,1)     ;
lmiterm([-1 1 1 Sigma3 ],hm^2,1/2) ;
lmiterm([-1 1 1 Sigma4 ],hm,1)     ;
lmiterm([-1 1 2 1 ],1,1)           ;
lmiterm([-1 2 1 0 ],Beta^-1)     ; 
lmiterm([-1 2 2 0 ],Delta^2)       ;


What is an LMI ?

Have you studied and do you understand https://www.mathworks.com/help/robust/ref/lmiterm.html ?

Why don't you answer my question ? Do you realize that there are thousands of acronyms with 3 letters ? Explaining  a little or giving at least a reference is a matter of politeness towards people who can help you. Moreover you don't say in which Matlab library function "lmiterm" is to be found.

@ Jean Marie .Thank you for your response.I meant  linear-matrix-inequality (LMI)
